# Is it possible to build a radar that is shielded behind one meter of ceramic material and still detect people 500 meters away?

Tags: electrical-engineering, ceramics, radar

I saw that there are radars which can detect people behind walls, so I wonder what the limitations of radars are when it comes to detecting people while being protected behind thick ceramic shield.

Comment: See closed on EE.SE. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/696947/is-it-possible-to-build-a-radar-that-is-shielded-behind-one-meter-of-ceramic-mat.

Comment: Why it fits chemistry more than engineering?, isn't engineering also about materials like ceramics?. I just don't know where to ask this question, it fits to electrical engineering but still got closed

Comment: Personally, I think here or EE would be equally good, maybe better there but I'm not the one that closed it.

Comment: EE stack exchange takes the position "is there an excuse for closing the question?" rather than "is there a question that can be answered?".

Comment: It will depend on the details of the ceramic material. anything to do with radar would probably be EE though

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing much about radar or radio-penetration of ceramics, I'll have to say a meter of almost anything is a lot. Generally, lower frequencies penetrate better so a lower frequency would give a better chance of getting through the ceramic barrier.  The bad news is, the lower the frequency, the lower the resolution.

There exist perimeter surveillance radar that is high frequency (5GHz and up) that works quite well watching for people.  The plant I used to work at had a microwave intruder detection system that would set off the radar detectors of cars driving near by on the highway.  That would not be able to pass through a meter of anything with much more density than air.

Ground-penetrating radar (GPR) can go through meters of material but does better with a special transducer in contact with the ground to broadcast and receive the resulting echoes (or lack thereof).  I dimly recall that GPR can detect voids underground but not what's inside the voids.  If you set up GPR with a meter thick [radome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radome), it could detect that there was an outside (gee) but not much else.

There also exist lower frequencies that could pass through a meter of solid material without (much) issue.  The problem is they are so low, they would pass through the ceramic and people on the outside, equally well.  But that's OK because with frequencies that low, the resolution would be such that you could not detect much of objects as small as a person (or a barn, either).

**The short version,**
No, I don't think so.

Comment: I saw something about GPR detecting underground water and decayed human remains, I guess it is at least a meter deep of soil, so can a radar work the same way to detect people who are further away but not buried behind several meters of soil?.

Comment: Well you can always increase the power to get through the ceramic as long as you can find a combination of ceramic and frequency with a transparency window, which is opaque to meatbag targets.

Comment: My understanding (which is far from complete) is that GPR works when the medium it is detecting through is continuous; it detects discontinuities, such as underground water or bodies.  The radar signal would have to go out, thru the wall (a big discontinuity), bounce off the people and back through the wall (another big discontinuity), to the detector.  I don't see it happening.  Meanwhile @DKNguyen
has a valid point.  If were lucky and found a material transparent to microwaves at a useful frequency but not transparent to people, you'd be all set, but don't hold your breath.

Comment: @user1683793 Doesn't glass qualify? Glass is transparent to at least some frequencies of radar.

Comment: @DKNguyen, Interesting.  Yes, if the glass was clear enough, you could _SEE_ people moving on the other side, if it is equally transparent to microwaves, radar would work.  Depending upon who you ask, glass is or is not a ceramic.  One place on the web says, "Ceramics are crystalline, while glasses are amorphous." While another says, "Glasses are a unique range of ceramic materials." Glass that clear exists, I seem to recall reading you could read a newspaper through a mile of the glass used for fiber optics, but such things are not common in bulk like a meter thick.